# Bash script ignores shell script to run

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script, My script ignores one shell script to run... How can I make it run?
12th line isn't working..

```bash
clear
pkill -f ts3server
clear
echo -e "${RENK4}TeamSpeak3 Sunucunuzun Query (YaTQA) Şifresi Ne Olmalı?"
echo -n -e "${RENK2}Cevap=${RENK5} "

read Cevap30
ts3_sifre_sifirlama=$Cevap30

clear
cd /home/fixscript/ts3server
sh ./ts3server_startscript.sh start serveradmin_password=$ts3_sifre_sifirlama #This code isn't running...
clear
echo -e "${RENK3}TeamSpeak Sunucunuzun Query (YaTQA) Şifresi${RENK2} Değiştirildi."
echo -e "${RENK3}Yönetim Menüsüne yönlendiriliyorsunuz..."
teamspeak_yonetim
```

Comment: You are invoking it with `/bin/sh`, which is a symlink to the Dash shell. If it's a Bash script, invoke it with `/bin/bash`, or just the script itself with a proper shebang.

Comment: `read $Cevap30` should almost certainly be `read Cevap30`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I'm creating a bash script, but this bash script should run a shell script file. Thats why I wrote "`sh ./ts3server_startscript.sh start serveradmin_password=$ts3_sifre_sifirlama`"

Comment: Unless the script contains plain sh or dash specific code, use "bash" instead of "sh".

Comment: Okey @Hannu, thank you! But still didn't solved my problem.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you too for correcting me. I don't know why I did too many error on this such a short code

Comment: @mchid Hello! No, That doesn't answer my question. Latest common doesn't answer my question too.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"isn't running"*? Shell commands that fail normally emit error messages.

Comment: Did you run `shellcheck` on all your scripts? This should be the first thing you do every time. And also, how should anybody know why it isn't running when we don't know the contents?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: For debugging, invoke your script with `bash -x ./ts3server_startscript.sh`. What do you mean by "isn't  running/working"? There are many, many ways to not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: edit your post above and add `<hr><pre>` then do hit CTRL-L in a shell, then do `cat /home/fixscript/ts3server/ts3server_startscript.sh` followed by CTRL-A, CTRL-SHIFT-C) and finally paste (CTRL-V) it above and append a `</pre>` to it, save.